# Why join in spark in local mode is so slow?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am using spark in local mode and a simple join is taking too long. I have fetched two dataframes: A (8 columns and 2.3 million rows) and B(8 columns and 1.2 million rows) and joining them using `A.join(B,condition,'left')` and called an action at last. It creates a single job with three stages, each for two dataframes extraction and one for joining. Surprisingly stage with extraction of dataframe A is taking around 8 minutes and that of dataframe B is taking 1 minute. And join happens within seconds. My important configuration settings are:

1. spark.master                      local[*]
2. spark.driver.cores                8
3. spark.executor.memory             30g
4. spark.driver.memory               30g
5. spark.serializer                  org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
6. spark.sql.shuffle.partitions      16

The only executor is driver itself. While extracting dataframes, i have partitioned it in 32(also tried 16,64,50,100,200) parts. I have seen shuffle write memory to be 100 MB for Stage with dataframe A extraction. So to avoid shuffle i made 16 initial partitions for both dataframes and broadcasted dataframe B(smaller), but it is not helping. There is still shuffle write memory. I have used `broadcast(B)` syntax for this. **Am I doing something wrong? Why shuffling is still there?** Also when i see event timelines its showing only four cores are processing at any point of time. Although I have a 2core*4 processor machine.**Why is that so?**

Comment: what is the size of the input?

Comment: Dataframe A contains 280MB and same is 140MB for B

Comment: Those are very small datasets ... maybe this?
 https://bzhangusc.wordpress.com/2015/06/10/why-your-join-is-so-slow/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, "Join"<=>Shuffling, the big question here is how uniformly are your data distributed over partitions (see for example https://0x0fff.com/spark-architecture-shuffle/ , https://www.slideshare.net/SparkSummit/handling-data-skew-adaptively-in-spark-using-dynamic-repartitioning and just Google the problem). 
Few possibilities to improve efficiency:

- think more about your data (A and B) and partition data wisely;
- analyze, are your data skewed?;
- go into UI and look at the tasks timing;
- choose such keys for partitions that during "join" only few partitions from dataset A shuffle with few partitions of B;